# printf imprimindo números estranhos

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

void main()
{
    int i, n;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    printf("Digite um número: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    printf("\nSequência decrescente de %d até 1", n);
    for (i=n; i>=1; i--)
    {
        printf("%d\n\n", i);
    }
    printf("Sequência crescente de 1 até %d", n);
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n\n", i);
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
Digite um número: 5

Sequência decrescente de 5 até 15

4

3

2

1

Sequência crescente de 1 até 51  

2

3

4

5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na chamada inicial da função `printf` que não possui o `\n` no final para pular a linha antes de começar a exibir os valores ao `STDOUT`:

```
printf("\nSequência decrescente de %d até 1", n);
```

Por isso que, quando inseriu `5`, a mensagem exibiu `15`, **pois o primeiro `printf` chamado dentro do seu laço de repetição `for` apareceu na mesma linha do `printf` inicial, juntando `1` com `5`**.

Basta inserir o caractere `\n` **ao final dos seus `printf` fora dos laços de repetição**, como no exemplo:

```
printf("\nSequência decrescente de %d até 1\n", n);
```

A partir disso, o primeiro `printf` dentro do laço de repetição será exibido em uma nova linha.

Comment: Muito obrigado! deixei este detalhe passar